# CLLocation is Null in my xamarin.ios project

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios, cllocationmanager

I am fetching GPS coordinates in my xamarin.ios project using CLLocationManager, It was working fine till yesterday , today Its crashing by throwing this [image: this] null exception at this line

```
double lat = locationManager.Location.Coordinate.Latitude;
```

following is my code

```
    if (CLLocationManager.LocationServicesEnabled) {
                    double lat = locationManager.Location.Coordinate.Latitude;
                    double lon = locationManager.Location.Coordinate.Longitude;

                    CLLocationCoordinate2D mapCenter = new CLLocationCoordinate2D (lat, lon);
}
```

I have deleted the app and re installed , I have restarted the xamarin studio but no luck, could any one help me out

Comment: I'm not a xamarin guy but in Objective-C it is valid to access methods/properties on `nil` pointer

Comment: which specific object is null?  Have you verified that you have started received location updates before you start checking the value of location?

Comment: Where is the code for when you instantiate locationManager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your check for `CLLocationManager.LocationServicesEnabled` I would also check for:

```
CLLocationManager.Status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedAlways
```

Incase the user has declined the use of their location. Check out the enum [CLAuthorizationStatus](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/CoreLocation.CLAuthorizationStatus/) for all the different situations your app might use, e.g. `AuthorizedWhenInUse`. Also check the permissions in the settings to see if your app is allowed